# Splitting up a string from a file and assigning variables

Tags: python, string, file, pygame

I'm making a pygame and I'm trying to add a highscore feature but I can't quite figure out how

I'm saving the names and scores into a .txt file like this example:

```
christian careaga: 500
c dubb: 400
swag master: 50
```

in the .txt each score and name are placed on a new line

I want to take each score and assign it to its own variable like this

```
score1 = christian careaga: 500
score2 = c dubb: 400
score3 = swag master: 50
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Your best bet is to create a list. Use `f.readlines()`.

Comment: I don't think you want to assign them all to variables, then you would have to reference all of them by name to find the max. It would be better to use a while loop and just search for the max.

Comment: thats true but i still need them split and when i display them my game i have to have a way to identify them whether its in a list or using variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create variables for each score in your file, use a dictionary instead:

```
with open("scores.txt") as f:
    scores = {'score{}'.format(i) : line.strip() for i,line in enumerate(f,1)}
```

Now access scores like this:

```
>>> scores['score1']
'christian careaga: 500'
>>> scores['score2']
'c dubb: 400'
>>> scores['score3']
'swag master: 50'
```

Get the score in sorted order:

```
>>> for s in  sorted(scores.values(), key = lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]),
                                                                 reverse = True):
    print s
...     
christian careaga: 500
c dubb: 400
swag master: 50
```

Comment: that worked do you think there is a way to get the scores highest to lowest?

Comment: @ChristianCareaga you can sort the dict to do that, see my edit. Are the names always unique?

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself some grief and use a format that is easier to both write and parse. The [`json` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) would save and load data without additional parsing:

```
import json

# write highscores
with open('highscores', 'w') as hscores:
    json.dump(my_hiscores_structure, hscores, indent=4)

# load highscores
with open('highscores', 'r') as hscores:
    my_hiscores_structure = json.load(hscores)
```

By using `indent=4` you write out a structure that is quite readable too.

Comment: would there be an easy way to go this and get the scores highest to lowest?

Comment: @ChristianCareaga: Just sort the structure; see the [Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) for tips on how to sort python lists and such.